# ElasticSearch - get all available filters (aggregate) from index

Tags: elasticsearch

Let's say I have:

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "products",
        "_type": "product",
        "_id": "599c2b3fc991ee0a597034fa",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {,
          "attributes": {
            "1": [
              "a"
            ],
            "2": [
              "b",
              "c"
            ],
            "3": [
              "d",
              "e"
            ],
            "4": [
              "f",
              "g"
            ],
            "5": [
              "h",
              "i"
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "products",
        "_type": "product",
        "_id": "599c4bb4b970c25976ced8bd",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "attributes": {
            "1": [
              "z"
            ],
            "2": [
              "y"
            ]
          }
        }
```

Each product has attributes. Each attribute has ID and a value. I can filter the products by attributes fine but for now I am creating the "possible attributes" list from MongoDB. I would like to find a way to generate such a list from ElasticSearch alone (and maybe just query MongoDB for additional data).

What I need is:

```
{
  1: [a, z],
  2: [b, c, y],
  etc.
}
```

How would such a aggregation look like? Get all available attributes (grouped by `attribute.id`) with all of their possible values (throughout all products)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot do it in one query but it is fairly easy in two:

#### Retrieving the list of attributes

You can use mapping to get all the fields in your documents:

```bash
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/your_index/your_type/_mapping"
```

#### Retrieving their values

You can then use multiple [Terms aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) to get all the values of a field:

```bash
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/your_index/your_type/_search" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "field1Values": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "field1",
        "size": 20
      }
    },
    "field2Values": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "field2",
        "size": 20
      }
    },
    "field3Values": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "field3",
        "size": 20
      }
    },
    ...
  }
}'
```

This retrieve the top 20 most frequents values for each field.

This limit of 20 values is a restriction to prevent a huge response (if you have a few billion documents with a unique fields for instance). You can modify the "size" parameters of the terms aggregation to increase it. From your requirements I guess choosing something 10x larger than a rough estimate of the number of different values taken by each field should do the trick.

#### How to handle huge cardinality on values

You can also do an intermediate query using the [cardinality aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-cardinality-aggregation.html) to get this actual value and then use it as the size of your term aggregation. Please note than cardinality is an estimate when it comes to large number so you may want to use `cardinality * 2`.

```bash
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/your_index/your_type/_search" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "field1Cardinality": {
      "cardinality": {
        "field": "field1"
      }
    },
    "field2Cardinality": {
      "cardinality": {
        "field": "field2"
      }
    },
    "field3Cardinality": {
      "cardinality": {
        "field": "field3"
      }
    },
    ...
  }
}'
```

#### How to handle huge cardinality on values

The previous works if there is not so many different attributes.
If there is, you should alter how the documents are stored to prevent a [Mapping explosion](https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-crash-elasticsearch#mapping-explosion),

Storing them like this:

```js
{
    "attributes":[
        {
            "name":"1",
            "value":[
                "a"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name":"2",
            "value":[
                "b",
                "c"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name":"3",
            "value":[
                "d",
                "e"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name":"4",
            "value":[
                "f",
                "g"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name":"5",
            "value":[
                "h",
                "i"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Would fix the problem and you will be able to use a term aggregation on "name" and then a sub terms aggregation on "value" to get what you want:

```bash
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/your_index/your_type/_search" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "attributes": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "attributes.name",
        "size": 1000
      },
      "aggs": {
        "values": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "attributes.value",
            "size": 100
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

It requires to use a [Nested mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html) for attributes.

Comment: I agree with @Pandawan . You can not do a terms aggregation on analyzed text fields, use the `_field_stats` / `_field_caps` API to tell apart which fields are suitable for terms aggregation. You could cache the field list in memory because it shouldn't change frequently. The _nested_ type has a negative impact on performance and makes querying/aggregating complicated. The indices (mappings indeed) are _limited to 1000 fields_ by default in order to avoid mapping explosion.

Comment: It sounds really good, it seems to fit my use case perfectly.