# Fielddata on nested keys elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.4/fielddata.html

I have a structure that is like this:

```
{
    ...,
    attributes: {
        'attribute_1': ['value_1', 'value_2'],
        'attribute_2': ['value_2', 'value_3'],
    }
}
```

etc. I can refactor it to:

```
{
    ...,
    attributes: [
        {
            name: 'attribute_1',
            values: ['value_1', 'value_2']
        }
    ]
}
```

if needed. I'm trying to get all values (UUIDs) for each of the attributes (they are UUIDs as well) but it seems that for Term Aggregation which was suggested here [ElasticSearch - get all available filters (aggregate) from index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46298924/elasticsearch-get-all-available-filters-aggregate-from-index), I need them to have `fielddata=true`.

Since I don't know the attribute IDs when mapping how to set `fielddata` on all children keys of `attributes`? Either in the version A or I can refactor to B (I will at some point anyway) if needed.

Also if there is any other way to skip the `fielddata=true` problem I'd gladly hear it.

The current mappings for the attributes:

```
"attributes": {
    "properties": {
        "name": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                }
            }
        },
        "values": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                }
            }
        }
    }
},
```

Comment: Basically I'm looking for something like (pseudo-code): `"attributes.*": fielddata=true`.

Comment: for skip fielddata=true that required a high RAM consumption you could make your field type keyword, instead of text type. Then you can make aggregation without any other setting

Comment: Ok, but how can I add a mapping/type with a wildcard? I'm using Node.js, but anything would be useful. Could you elaborate and make it an answer?

Comment: wildcard? Wildcard is a query for keyword datatype, if you have used that query for text type you will note speed improvements. You don't need to set a special mapping for make that keyword field works.

Comment: When I index the documents they automatically get type `text`. I need to tell that `attributes.*.values` is an array of `type: keyword`.

Comment: ok, i will help you. Could you please post your index mapping? GET /<your_index>/_mapping

Comment: I have added additional information on mappings (for attributes) in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

You just have a keyword field for that field. You don't need to change your mapping. Your fields type are an object fields, so instead of query wildcard or aggregation against `values` or `name` fields you have to query against `values.keyword` or `name.keyword` fields. Enjoy!

Comment: I want to do the body: `{
        size: 0,
        aggs: {
          attributes: {
            terms: {
              field: 'attributes.name.keyword',
              size: 100,
            },
            aggs: {
              values: {
                terms: {
                  field: 'attributes.values.keyword',
                  size: 100,
                },
              },
            },
          },
        },
      },` are you sure it should work out-of-the-box? I don't see any results.

Comment: ah, sure sorry. With the object field you don't keep the relationship between the two fields: https://www.elastic.co/blog/managing-relations-inside-elasticsearch So, if you want to make an aggregation of aggregation for multifield you have to change your mapping to nested type and then make a nested aggregation https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-nested-aggregation.html